# Taking Control of WPF elements

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have an integer array declared in a class. Using that array, a PolyLine is drawn on a grid. The elements of the array are the y-coordinates. The array has to updated continuously and then the values are to be displayed. My idea of implementing this is to have two threads. One to update the values of the array and the other to print PolyLine on the grid.
Updating the array is not a problem. When I try to print PolyLine on the grid using the code below, an exception is thrown with the following message: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."
Kindly suggest a workaround for this problem using thread. Perhaps, an event may be used instead of thread? I am open to suggestions. Any help is appreciated!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Polyline Wave = new Polyline();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Refresh();
        DisplyOnGrid();
        ThreadStart child = new ThreadStart(DisplyOnGrid);
        Thread _DisplayOnGrid = new Thread(child);
        _DisplayOnGrid.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        _DisplayOnGrid.Start();
    }

    private void DisplyOnGrid()
    {
        Wave.Stroke = Brushes.Yellow;
        Wave.StrokeThickness = 1.25;
        for (int i = 0; i < DisplayGrid.Width; i++)
        {
            Wave.Points.Add(new Point(i, 50));
        }
        DisplayGrid.Children.Add(Wave);
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        DisplayGrid.Children.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you removing the Polyline from the Grid and then add it again? You could instead simply replace its `Points` collection. Besides that, you should use a Dispatcher as shown in the answer, or probably don't use a Thread at all, and a DispatcherTimer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting Error because you are trying to access object which is owned by UI/Dispatcher thread
try something like this:

```
 private void DisplyOnGrid()
 {
   Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=> 
   {
    Wave.Stroke = Brushes.Yellow;
    Wave.StrokeThickness = 1.25;
    for (int i = 0; i < DisplayGrid.Width; i++)
    {
        Wave.Points.Add(new Point(i, 50));
    }
    DisplayGrid.Children.Add(Wave);
   }

 ))};
```